# Need a regular expression for extracting a description section from my Git tag version strings

Tags: regex, git, powershell, version-control

I currently have the following PS script to extract the SW version from a Git tag and integrate it into the built assembly.
This works for tags like `v1.2.3` and creates file-versions and product-versions such as e.g. `1.2.3.16` and  `1.2.3.16-13b05b79`

```
# Get version info from Git. For example: v1.2.3-45-g6789abc
$gitVersion = git describe --match "v[0-9]*" --long --always --dirty;

# Get name of current branch
$gitBranch = git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD;

# Write Git information to version.txt
$versionFile = $args[1] + "\version.txt";
"version: " + $gitVersion > $versionFile;
"branch: " + $gitBranch >> $versionFile;

# Parse Git version info into semantic pieces
$gitVersion -match '[v](.*)-(\d+)-[g](.+)$';
$gitTag = $Matches[1];
$gitCount = $Matches[2];
$gitSHA1 = $Matches[3];

# Define file variables
$assemblyFile = $args[0] + "\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs";

# Read template file, overwrite place holders with git version info
$newAssemblyContent = Get-Content $assemblyFile |
    %{$_ -replace '\$FILEVERSION\$', ($gitTag + "." + $gitCount) } |
    %{$_ -replace '\$INFOVERSION\$', ($gitTag + "." + $gitCount + "-" + $gitSHA1) };

echo "Injecting Git Version Info to AssemblyInfo.cs"
$newAssemblyContent > $assemblyFile;
```

I would now like to extend the regex in this script, so that I can use tags with a brief description such as `v1.2.3-description`, where `description` can be of variable length.
Ideally, the regex should allow for dashes in the description so that `v1.2.3-description-with-dashes` would also be valid and any other characters that are allowed in Git tags.

What makes this difficult for me (I have tried) is that `git describe` command will output this as `v1.2.3-description-with-dashes-16`, how I can distinguish between the dashes that belong to the Git-output and those that belong to the description.

Comment: I get what you're trying to achieve. I don't get _why_! This definitely feels like a bad idea. Your version numbers shouldn't include that information. Perhaps there's somewhere better in the assembly file to put your git tags?

Comment: Mostly, I want this to be able to append something like 'dev', 'alpha', 'beta', 'rc' to the version string, but I thought I would make it as flexible as possible. Nevertheless, perhaps this can be avoided by using good version-numbering scheme, perhaps this can be avoided(?).

Comment: A list of known, good tags would be better than allowing all-the-things. SemVer has some documentation on this type of thing (search for "pre-release")

Comment: `$version, $description = $version -split '-'; $description = $description -join '-'` This will accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: @gvee I guess that makes sense. But that still leaves me with the problem of having to parse out a pre-release-description that is optional and therefore might or might not be there. E.g.: `v1.2.3-123-gd9b5a775-dirty` vs. `v1.2.3-rc.1-123-gd9b5a775-dirty`. I don't know how to do that either unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Using RegEx (and using the new examples) this is what you can do:

```
$gitVersion -match '(?<tag>v\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(?:-?(?<description>\D+)?)(?:-?(?<count>\d+)?)(?:-?(?<sha1>gd[0-9a-f]+))(?:-?(?<dirty>.+)?)'

$gitTag         = $Matches['tag']
$gitDescription = ($Matches['description']).Trim("-")
$gitCount       = if($Matches['count']) { $Matches['count'] } else { 1 }  # if no count is found, we assume 1 ??
$gitSHA1        = $Matches['sha1']
$gitDirty       = $Matches['dirty']
```

Testresults:

> ```
> teststring                                          tag     description               count sha1      dirty
> --------------------------------------------------- ------- ------------------------- ----- --------- -----
> v1.2.3-123-gd9b5a775-dirty                          v1.2.3                            123   gd9b5a775 dirty
> v1.2.3-description-123-gd9b5a775-dirty              v1.2.3  description-              123   gd9b5a775 dirty
> v1.2.3-description-with-dashes-123-gd9b5a775-dirty  v1.2.3  description-with-dashes-  123   gd9b5a775 dirty
> v1.2.3-description-with-dashes-123-gd9b5a775        v1.2.3  description-with-dashes-  123   gd9b5a775   
> v1.2.3-description-with-dashes-gd9b5a775            v1.2.3  description-with-dashes-        gd9b5a775   
> v1.2.3-45-gd9b5a775                                 v1.2.3                            45    gd9b5a775   
> v1.2.3-gd9b5a775                                    v1.2.3                                  gd9b5a775
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the string you use are not what is actually returnd by the Git-command.
These are in the correct format:

`v1.2.3-123-gd9b5a775-dirty`

`v1.2.3-description-123-gd9b5a775-dirty`

`v1.2.3-description-with-dashes-123-gd9b5a775-dirty`

and the same without the appended `-dirty`, if the working directory is clean.

Comment: You should have given the correct examples in the question to work with. Now it was just a waste of time..

Comment: Ok, I have redone the regex using the new examples you gave. Have a look!

Comment: @packoman Did you see the edited answer? I forgot to "ping" you.

Comment: Yep. I saw it, but did not yet have time to test it. Thanks for the heads-up and the udpate. Will get back to this as ASAP.